# coordinates inside-outside the rectangle

Tags: javascript, coordinates, rectangles

To check the x and y coordinates inside or outside the rectangle 
I have four_coordinates NE,SW,NW,SE  if x and Y coordinates intersect within this four_coordinates function as true else it should be false 
IF x and Y value not within this four coordinates it should return false But i am getting True; 
This Fiddle shows that the function is currently returning true.

jsFiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/uwv249vc/

```
 function is_inside(point, loc) {
  var x_min = 12.306879896962968,
  x_max = 76.66268348693848,
  y_min = 12.297236015659891,
  y_max = 76.67736053466797


var  x =12.283985584345864,
y = 76.67015075683594;

var top_left = [x_min, y_min],
    top_right = [x_max, y_max],
    bottom_left = [x_max, y_min],
    bottom_right = [x_min, y_max];

console.log("top_left : " + top_left);
console.log("top_right : " + top_right);
console.log("bottom_left : " + bottom_left);
console.log("bottom_right : " + bottom_right);

var rectangle_value = [top_left, bottom_left, bottom_right, top_right];
console.log("rectangle_value" + rectangle_value);
for (var i = 0, j = rectangle_value.length - 1; i < rectangle_value.length; j = i++) {

    var xi = rectangle_value[i][0],
        yi = rectangle_value[i][1];

    var xj = rectangle_value[j][0],
        yj = rectangle_value[j][1];
    console.log("xi :" + xi + "yi :" + yi);
    console.log("xj :" + xj + "yj :" + yj);
    var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);

    return intersect;
 }
}




console.log(is_inside())  //this must be false
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: function should be false the x and y value i providing below the the top_left,top_right,bottom_left,bottom_right

Comment: You've got a for loop that iterates rectangle_value but you're returning the first time through the loop, effectively only testing for i = 0. is that logic correct?

Comment: I have a map when i place a  markers and i need to be able to find marker is within the rectangle bounds are outside the rectangle bounds